# Regular expression that validates a CSS selector

Tags: java, regex, css-selectors

What is a regular expression that can be used to validate a CSS selector, and can do so in a way that a invalid selector halts quickly.

Valid selectors:

```
EE
#myid
.class
.class.anotherclass
EE .class
EE .class EEE.anotherclass
EE[class="test"]
.class[alt~="test"]
#myid[alt="test"]
EE:hover
EE:first-child
E[lang|="en"]:first-child
EE#test .class>.anotherclass
EE#myid.classshit.anotherclass[class~="test"]:hover
EE#myid.classshit.anotherclass[class="test"]:first-child EE.Xx:hover
```

Invalid selectors, e.g. contain extra whitespace at the end of the line:

```
EE:hover   EE
EE .class EEE.anotherclass 
EE#myid.classshit.anotherclass[class="test"]:first-child EE.Xx:hov     9
EE#myid.classshit.anotherclass[class="test"]:first-child EE.Xx:hov  -daf
```

Comment: You might be able to write a RE for this, but are you sure that writing a grammar parser wouldn't be better?

Comment: I was just about to post an answer at your other question but you deleted it.

Comment: *"Invalid selectors, e.g. contain extra whitespace at the end of the line:"* What line would that be? I've never run into a CSS parser (e.g., for a CSS file, style attribute, etc) that had issues with trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool. CSS selectors are way to complex. 
Example:

```
bo\
dy:not(.\}) {}
```

Use a parser with a real tokenizer like this one: [PHP-CSS-Parser](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Parser). It is easier to rewrite it to Java than getting regex right.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Regex that I use in my codes:

```
[+>~, ]?\s*(\w*[#.]\w+|\w+|\*)+(:[\w\-]+\([\w\s\-\+]*\))*(\[[\w ]+=?[^\]]*\])*([#.]\w+)*(:[\w\-]+\([\w\s\-\+]*\))*
```

After tokenized I use the trim function to remove extra spaces e.g.:

expression:

```
EE.class      EE#id.class
```

tokens:

```
EE.class

   EE#id.class
```

tokens after trim:

EE.class

EE#id.class

OR e.g.

>EE.class (Alert when it's a direct child, then I treat with any substring code )

Other routines can check if token is a number e.g.

You can use http://regexpal.com/ for tests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with yer typical regular expression is that they are unable to handle arbitrary levels of nesting.  They have no memory. Consider a string of some number of a's followed by the same number of b's: `aaabbb` and a reasonable regexp `a*b*`. When the regexp gets to the first 'b' it has no memory how many a's it recognized and therefore it can't recognize the same number of b's.

Now replace a and b with `(` and `)`, `IF` and `END`, `<x>` and `</x>` etc... and you can see the problem.

Comment: I remember Jeff Atwood talking about not writing an XML parser with RegEx's for just that reason. I was just asking about the selector which has a simple grammar. Example: tag#id.aClass.anotherClass:pseudo-class[matching="element"]. Which could have a second selector provided but as long as there is one or more you don't care.